# Installing adobe acrobat reader firefox plugin ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, firefox, adobe, adobe-reader, firefox-extensions

I want to install adobe acrobat reader plugin in ubuntu 12.10. I tried enabling medibuntu and searched for mozilla-acroread and acroread-plugins, but the search yielded no results. I have adobe acrobat reader installed using the debian package.

One more method I tried is to open Adobe Acrobat Reader Edit -> Preferences -> Internet and then give the browser executables (/usr/bin/firefox) and html rendering library (/usr/lib/firefox)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit I did the following to install the Acrobat Reader plugin in for Firefox. (This assumes I have already manually installed Acrobat reader to /opt/Adobe/Reader9).

```
sudo apt-get install nspluginwrapper
sudo nspluginwrapper -i /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Browser/intellinux/nppdf.so
```

Now double check with:

```
nspluginwrapper -l
```

the output might look something like:

```
/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/npwrapper.nppdf.so
  Original plugin: /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Browser/intellinux/nppdf.so
  Plugin viewer: /usr/lib/nspluginwrapper/i386/linux/npviewer
  Wrapper version string: 1.4.4-1
/usr/lib/firefox/plugins/npwrapper.nppdf.so
  Original plugin: /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Browser/intellinux/nppdf.so
  Plugin viewer: /usr/lib/nspluginwrapper/i386/linux/npviewer
  Wrapper version string: 1.4.4-1
```

Restart Firefox, and double check the plugins:

```
Firefox >> File >> Open Location >> "about:plugins"
```

the output should contain:

```
Adobe Reader 9.5

  File: npwrapper.nppdf.so
  Version: 
  The Adobe Reader plugin is used to enable viewing of PDF and FDF files from within 
  the browser. 
  ...
```

Hopefully it should be working now.